# Compressing game with reinflate method

Tags: inno-setup, compression

I have recently known that reinflate method of compression of games is much better than precomp so anyone can please tell me that how can i compress games with reinflate + srep + lzma.
This means tell me the code to create batch file which i could use for my compression.i use precomp +srep +lzma method  just now .

And yes please tell me how can i unpack these compressed files with inno setup i.e what code i have to add.

One guy just comprssed gta v to 29 gb with reinflate

Comment: What is "reinflate"? Is there some tool that supports it? How are you using *"precomp +srep +lzma method just now"*?

Comment: Reinflate is a process of of compressing files using raw2hif.dll etc i dont know it all but i know this that it expand a file to maximum extent and then srep and lzma are used to compress that extended file . And just now i only know the codes for compression with precomp + srep + lzma and ineed codes for reinflate+ srep + lzma

Comment: I didn't even found any credible information about `raw2hif`

Comment: Thnx martin for searching . I got some info on reinflate compession on fileforums.com but i didnt understand that .see if you could understand.

Comment: Here u can read about it:http://fileforums.com/archive/index.php/t-96138.html

Comment: Well, then your should first ask a question, how to compress/decompress files with "reinflate" (possible on [su] as that does not look like a programming question). And once you learn that, you can come here, show us how to use "reinflate", and ask how to implement the procedure in the Inno Setup. As stated now, your question is a way too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To shed some light on this question, it's about my tool [Precomp](https://github.com/schnaader/precomp-cpp) that can help to further compress already compressed files. It's decompressing compressed content like zlib streams and finds out which compression parameters have to be used to get the bit-exact compressed stream back. After that, compressed streams can be replaced by decompressed data and the resulting file can be compressed better than the original file using advanced compression methods like 7-Zip.

The mentioned "reinflate" actually is [reflate](http://encode.ru/threads/1399-reflate-a-new-universal-deflate-recompressor?highlight=reflate), a similar closed source alternative that uses a more sophisticated approach to achieve better results - it works on every zlib stream because it doesn't brute force zlib parameters, but reimplements zlib and (roughly speaking) stores a diff of the used zlib codes. For more information, see [Precomp issue #21](https://github.com/schnaader/precomp-cpp/issues/21).

Unfortunately, reflate usage is quite complicated and there is no further development, so my best advice would be to ask the question at the [encode.ru](http://encode.ru/) forum.

Comment: Thnx for advice bro